# Call a method contained inside a jQuery AJAX that is contained inside a method of the same class

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop, javascript-objects

I have been trying to access some methods of the same class from an AJAX call inside one of the methods but it does not work. What could be the issue here? I get this error `Uncaught TypeError: this.createTimeline is not a function` see the comments on the code below!

```
//sequenceRender is the class and below is one method
sequenceRender.prototype.ajaxSequence = function(){
    this.ajaxSequence = $.ajax('getSequence.php', {
                    dataType: 'json',
                    timeout: 2000
                });

   this.ajaxSequence.done(function (data, status, jqXhr) {
      console.log(data)
      this.SEQUENCE=data // I cannot access properties 
      this.createTimeline() // or methods from same class
      this.createWells() // from inside here

   })

  this.ajaxSequence.fail(function (jqXhr, textStatus, errorMessage) {
     console.log(errorMessage)
  })
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like `this` is going to have different values as you are trying to call this inside a event

Try adding the changes below and let me know if this works for you

```
sequenceRender.prototype.ajaxSequence = function() {
    mainContext = this;
    this.ajaxSequence = $.ajax('getSequence.php', {
                    dataType: 'json',
                    timeout: 2000
                });

   this.ajaxSequence.done(function (data, status, jqXhr) {
      console.log(data)
      mainContext.SEQUENCE=data 
      mainContext.createTimeline() // call the 'this' from here
      mainContext.createWells()

   })

  this.ajaxSequence.fail(function (jqXhr, textStatus, errorMessage) {
     console.log(errorMessage)
  })
}
```